# Remove/Override previous session when new session started in same machine separate Browser window

Tags: asp.net, session-state

I opened a browser and logged in to a website by storing user data in a Session object and sets timeout of Session object to 30 mins. And now I opened a another window in Browser opened same website and website asking the user for log in again, Ok now I again logged in but with different credentials. Now in my machine multiple users logged in to the same site, this looks odd to me because one user has already logged in the same machine when second tries to login then the previous session should override with new one or previous session should close and new session should starts.

how to do this Please help me...:)

Comment: what would you gain from doing this?

Comment: @Hoshani If a session has already started means how could you allow other user to login with his credentials in same computer to same website ?, either Session should continue with same user or Session should override to new user

Comment: the question states __different credentials__!!

Comment: **(different credentials means user 2)** user1 session has already started, if user 2 logged in means he( user 2 ) should override previous ( user1 ) session

Comment: In that case there is one idea I believe it will work, you have to save the user's device information (ip address, mac address, etc.) then whenever someone logs in you check their device existence against the information you have and do the suitable action accordingly.